# perl : how to share variables and subroutines across various perl files

Tags: perl, perl-module, data-sharing

I am trying something of this sort:

main.pl

```
use YAML::XS
our $yaml_input = YAML::XS::LoadFile("$input_file");
parse_yaml($yaml_input); 
#this variable has to be passed to the function parse_yaml which is in other file.
```

parser.pl

```
sub parse_yaml($yaml_input)
{
#some processing
}
```

I have read few answers about using a package but how do we use it in this case.

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on how  to create modules. [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for example. However, without a clearer explanation, we can't really answer your question. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could bless an object of your module and then use it access variables, subroutines in your main.pl. For using a variable you will be using `$module::variablename`. Let me know if this clarifies things.

Comment: @AbhiNickz : i did that to access variable, how to do the same for function?

Comment: @AbhiNickz: i got it , we have to use &modulename::function()

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to *import* the `parse_yaml` subroutine into you current program, rather than trying to export the value of the parameter, but I'm uncertain why you have written your own `parse_yaml` utility when `YAML::XS::LoadFile` has already done it for you

This is all very clearly described in the documentation for the [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) module

Here's a brief example

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use YAML::XS 'LoadFile';
use MyUtils 'parse_yaml';

my $input_file = 'data.yaml';

my $yaml_input = LoadFile($input_file);

parse_yaml($input_file);
# this variable has to be passed to the function parse_yaml which is in other file.
```

#### MyUtils.pm

```
package MyUtils;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT_OK = 'parse_yaml';

sub parse_yaml {
    my ($yaml_file) = @_;

    # some processing
}

1;
```

Comment: parse_yaml() subroutine is written to take variable values from my yaml file. Loadfile just gives the pointer (reference0 to the first object in Yaml.